# Oracle - remove duplicated rows using union - is that really valid?

Tags: sql, oracle, union

I'm interested in removing duplicated rows from my table.
in duplicated I refer to two or more rows, all containing the same values for all columns.
there are multiple approaches found over the web, 
all eventually involve joining or grouping while all columns of interest should be named explicitly.
this is not hard, but require writing the columns for each new table, 
and may be tedious if hundreds of columns are involved.

here is a naive question: union removes duplicated rows right?
could a generic query be:

```
create table new_table as
(
select * from old_table
union
select * from old_table
)
```

as in the following example:

```
with tmp as
(
select 1 as a, 2 as b from dual
union all
select 1 as a, 2 as b from dual
)
select * from tmp
union
select * from tmp

A B
- - 
1 2
```

this seems to be a simple solution, which does not require any config but the table name.

what am I missing? or this is fully valid?

thanks

Comment: This is fully valid.  I would add a comment saying `-- intentionally using union to remove duplicates`.

Comment: What's wrong  with using `select distinct * from old_table`?

Comment: `UNION` is the short form of `UNION DISTINCT`. (And `SELECT` is the short form of `SELECT ALL`...)

Comment: I think I understood my confusion - select unique rows is easy -     'select distinct * from table'     however delete duplicated rows from an existing table is more complex and requires naming all columns via grouping /joining. or is it not?. can one delete duplicated rows from an existing table via easy statement as 'distinct *'?

Comment: Try searching for "remove duplicate" of "delete duplicate" here in SO; you'll find many good answers

Answer (score 2):

You method is valid and it works. I feel better way is to use `DISTINCT` keyword which is meant for this purpose.

```
select * from test;
A   B
------
1   2
1   2
1   2
1   2
1   2

   select distinct * from test
   A    B
  ------- 
   1    2
```

Answer (score 2):

Your approach is correct, but not that efficient and (IMHO) overcomplicated.

I made a simple test with a table like the following:

```
create table old_table(a number, b number);
begin
    for i in 1..5 loop
        insert into old_table select level, -level from dual connect by level <= 1000000;
        commit;
    end loop;
end;
```

With the `UNION` you get:

```
create table new_table as
(
    select * from old_table
    UNION
    select * from old_table
);
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation              | Name      | Rows  | Bytes |TempSpc| Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | CREATE TABLE STATEMENT |           |  9934K|   246M|       | 86405  (51)| 00:17:17 |
|   1 |  LOAD AS SELECT        | NEW_TABLE |       |       |       |            |          |
|   2 |   SORT UNIQUE          |           |  9934K|   246M|   343M| 86405  (51)| 00:17:17 |
|   3 |    UNION-ALL           |           |       |       |       |            |          |
|   4 |     TABLE ACCESS FULL  | OLD_TABLE |  4967K|   123M|       |  3039   (1)| 00:00:37 |
|   5 |     TABLE ACCESS FULL  | OLD_TABLE |  4967K|   123M|       |  3039   (1)| 00:00:37 |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

You can try to simplify the `UNION` by applying a filter on the second scan of the table:

```
create table new_table1 as
(
    select * from old_table
    UNION
    select * from old_table where null is not null
);
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation              | Name      | Rows  | Bytes |TempSpc| Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | CREATE TABLE STATEMENT |           |  4967K|   123M|       | 43291   (1)| 00:08:40 |
|   1 |  LOAD AS SELECT        | NEW_TABLE |       |       |       |            |          |
|   2 |   SORT UNIQUE          |           |  4967K|   123M|   171M| 43291   (1)| 00:08:40 |
|   3 |    UNION-ALL           |           |       |       |       |            |          |
|   4 |     TABLE ACCESS FULL  | OLD_TABLE |  4967K|   123M|       |  3039   (1)| 00:00:37 |
|*  5 |     FILTER             |           |       |       |       |            |          |
|   6 |      TABLE ACCESS FULL | OLD_TABLE |  4967K|   123M|       |  3039   (1)| 00:00:37 |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

And this is what `DISTINCT` does:

```
create table new_table2 as
(
    select distinct * from old_table
);
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation              | Name       | Rows  | Bytes |TempSpc| Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | CREATE TABLE STATEMENT |            |  4967K|   123M|       | 43203   (1)| 00:08:39 |
|   1 |  LOAD AS SELECT        | NEW_TABLE2 |       |       |       |            |          |
|   2 |   HASH UNIQUE          |            |  4967K|   123M|   171M| 39759   (1)| 00:07:58 |
|   3 |    TABLE ACCESS FULL   | OLD_TABLE  |  4967K|   123M|       |  3039   (1)| 00:00:37 |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

No matter the method, the result is the same, with no need to explicitly write all the column names :

```
SQL> select count(1) from new_table  union all
  2  select count(1) from new_table1 union all
  3  select count(1) from new_table2;

  COUNT(1)
----------
   1000000
   1000000
   1000000
```